# How do I remove the top bar that appears when sharing a tab using getDisplayMedia on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, get-display-media

when sharing a tab on Chrome using the `getDisplayMedia` function it will push the webpage down to display a bar indicating you are sharing one of your tabs in all of your tabs. This is shown below:

Shared tab:
[image: Shared Tab]

Tab used to share:
[image: Sharing Tab]

Random Tab:
[image]

**How do I hide this bar?**

I have tried the `surfaceSwitching` property on the mediaStream constraints but that just gets rid of this button that is initially there if you don't specify it (see below).
[image: Surface Switching]

I've looked online and found two others asking the same question on the chrome support forums but they were closed with no replies on them...

[How do you disable the "sharing this tab" message in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48583572?hl=en)
[Sharing tab alert never going away](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/20699597?hl=en)

**Is it even possible to hide this bar?**

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
// Function for creating MediaStreams
async function start(constraints) {
    let MediaStream = null;
    try {
        MediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
    return MediaStream;
}


/* EVENT LISTENERS */

// When the capture button is clicked
capture.addEventListener("click", async () => {

    const constraints = {
        video: {
            frameRate: 30,
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
            cursor: "always"
        },
        audio: {
            autoGainControl: false,
            echoCancellation: false,
            googAutoGainControl: false,
            noiseSuppresion: false
        },
        surfaceSwitching: "exclude"
    }
    
    // Create MediaStream
    let captureStream = await start(constraints);

    // Update frontend
    localVideo.srcObject = captureStream;

    // Connect to remote peer
    for (const track of captureStream.getTracks()) {
        pc.addTrack(track, captureStream);
    }

})
```

Useful links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia

Thanks,

~Naitzirch

Edit: Answer
I've looked around and it seems like it's **not possible** to remove this bar. What you can do however is **share your browser instead** of a browser tab and you will not have this bar.